# How do I recover Pale Moon browser-stored passwords from a crashed (login loop) Ubuntu multi-boot install?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, login, password

I have tried every single remedy from about 2 weeks of internet searches on "how to fix Ubuntu login loop".

Nothing worked.

I was even able to correct some of the incomplete/incorrect remedies on webpage after a while.

I cannot get any new remedies, I give up on trying to rescue the partition, I just want to get the passwords off the old browser, and possibly rescue the files from the crashed install.

I asked what to do about the login loop issue a while ago and people stopped answering and I got left hanging.

Comment: Hi and welcome. What have you done to try and fix it? Exact steps commands and results. This way when someone tries to help you they do not tell you to do something you have already tried. BTW if the question is only in the title some users wont see it.

Comment: A quick search shows me they have their own support. https://forum.palemoon.org/

Comment: DAVID- Tried to fix video drivers, "splash" entry, checked "wxwxxwx" thing, checked .Xauthority stuff, removed old kernels, tried to reset .bashrc through moving it (but they gave bad commands on the advice webpage), tried to access through newer versions, tried to access/repair through DVD of original Ubuntu install, tried clean, autoremove, dpkg --configure -a, update --fix-missing, installed latest version of Ubuntu, pentagram drawn in toner and black candles and sacrificed a virgin video card (1 gb memory).

Comment: The first thing I check is free space in $HOME, as if there in insufficient space there, needed workfiles required for GUI login cause a login to fail without message; ie. login loop.  Text logins however will work; but you didn't mention all things that can cause login (disk full the most common in my experience unless you made changes in the prior session before you had the problem; where you'll have clues as you should remember what you did that is the likely cause; disk space is easily missed though I feel)

Comment: The additional info needs to be in the question so everyone can see it.

Comment: guiverc- I got the "insufficient space" error, I could only delete the old kernels. No access to any of the files on partition. I got 50 GB free, can't allocate to that partition through gparted.

Comment: Backup `.moonchild productions` from your /home/user directory with a live USB. Install Pale Moon on your new system. Copy the backed up `.moonchild productions` to your new install, putting it in the same place, and then open Pale Moon like you'd normally open it. You should have all the extensions, same open tabs, saved passwords, etc... You may need to take ownership of the directory and contents, but probably not.

Comment: I can't get into /home/user anything because I can't mount or unencrypt anything. Live Ubuntu doesn't matter if I can't unencrypt anything.

Comment: By the way, I deleted all the old kernels as a way to mitigate the "no space left" issue to no avail.

Comment: I was able to free up empty space by deleting files taking up the inodes but still login looping after upgrade, but at least updates went through, no more "no space" message.